# Select element by Class Name in a page with multiple elements - Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I 'm using Selenium WebDriver + C # to automate a test in a report. This report has a table with multiple columns and rows and each cell in this table has the class name composed by a name and a unique identifier (this identifier changes every time the report is generated ). Example:

< div title = " " class = " colSerialNumber s16-115435 - ec6e115435-96ee " ...

So, every row in the table has a cell "colSerialNumber".
My question is: Is there a way to find each "colSerialNumber" in selenium, selecting for its ocurrence by Class Name?

**Example:**

FindElement(By.ClassName(colSerialNumber(FirstOcurrence)))

FindElement(By.ClassName(colSerialNumber(SecondOcurrence)))

(I know the syntax is wrong, it's just an idea ...)

Something like nth-child used with CSS Selector.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note it has been some time since I used C#. If you call:

```
FindElements(By.ClassName("colSerialNumber"))
```

Note the plural **Elements**. This should give you a list of all matches. You can then use list indexes to find what you want: 1st, 2nd, ..., nth.