# Unable to select using class name - Selenium

Tags: css, selenium, select, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I need to select the below element using class since the id is dynamic.I don't want to loop through all the element, since class is unique here, However part of the class name is only match for every load i.e class name is not same for every load. Please help.

I have tried:

```
css = .hook--carrier-arrival-date hook--carrier-date text-input width--gamma nudge-half--bottom hasDatepicker
```

HTML:

```
<input id="dp1440532204966" class="hook--carrier-arrival-date hook--carrier-date text-input width--gamma nudge-half--bottom hasDatepicker" type="text" value="" data-validation="carrierArrivalDate" maxlength="10" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"/>
```

Comment: input id="dp1440532204966" class="hook--carrier-arrival-date hook--carrier-date text-input width--gamma nudge-half--bottom hasDatepicker" type="text" value="" data-validation="carrierArrivalDate" maxlength="10" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"

Comment: What have you tried? What programming language are you looking for? You didn't specify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select element by Class Name in a page with multiple elements - Selenium and C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715444/select-element-by-class-name-in-a-page-with-multiple-elements-selenium-and-c-s)

Comment: You didn't specify a language in the title or with tags so we don't know what language you want. You also didn't supply any previous code attempts so we don't know what you have tried.

Comment: @JeffC... I have added it in my first post itself what I have added.

Comment: If you weren't interested in a programming answer, why did you put the selenium related tags? When you tag something with selenium, people (like me) generally assume that you are looking for a code answer and want to know what language you need. I'm not sure why you're asking this now 5 months later.... and you still haven't marked the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how unique the element and it's attribute values are, this would still be a guess.

But, what is clear from the question, *you are not checking multiple classes correctly*. Join them with a dot instead. And, you don't need to check all of them, pick only "data-oriented":

```
input.hook--carrier-arrival-date.hook--carrier-date
```

---

Or, you can go further and check for "arrival-date" to be present in class:

```
input[class*="arrival-date"]
```

Note how readable and simple it is (though check that it's pointing the desired element).

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer.